# Replacement for Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver for a dbf file in a 64 bit Machine

Tags: c#, 64-bit, oledb, dbf

I recently moved to a 64 bit OS machine. In my application written in C# .net, a code in a dll is trying to open a dbf file using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver. I found that OLEDB is not supported for 64 bit. 
[Refer to this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/3d003721-6fb2-4927-9b29-bb6d7f35fa33)

I tried to install the new ACE.OLEDB.12.0. First I installed the 32 bit version of the engine, which was not recognized and received this error mesage "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine".

So I tried to install the 64 bit version of the ACE.OLEDB, from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en&WT.mc_id=soc-n-%5bTR%5d-loc-%5bServices%5d-%5bfarukc%5d)

Now I am facing an error as I have my other office products installed as 32-bit Office Products

**How can I resolve this issue?**

PS: I tried to set my solution to compile to x86 platform. It threw a BadImageFormatException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLEDB not being supported for 64 bit means that you can't load it into a 64 bit process, but if your process is 32 bit it will run just fine on a 64 bit machine. Windows has a very extensive compatibility layer to make 32 bit applications run on 64 bit machines.

If you don't require 64 bit functionality in your application (as your PS line suggests) you should set to compile to x86 and use the 32 bit Jet driver with it. This should run fine on both 32 and 64 bit systems.

On the BadImageFormatException, you probably tried to load the 64 bit dll into the 32 bit process.

Comment: No. for the BadImageFormatException. I downgraded my application to compile to x86 and tried to start my WCF Services. There is one particular project that is throwing this error.

Comment: I don't know how WCF works, is your service hosted by another process like IIS or something? In any way the .exe which originally starts the process needs to be 32 bit. I know it works because we're using the Jet OLEDB driver both in a WinForms-exe and in an IIS web application to read MsAccess mdb files. They work on 64 bit systems when the hosting process is a 32 bit process.